# Named pipe not found when using WCF netNamedPipeBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, netnamedpipebinding

I am the developer of a WCF service. My test clients work very well with it. But when it comes to real clients (using the same client proxy), it fails. The same WCF service works with netTcpBinding, this error occurs only with netNamedPipeBinding, even with ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single

Here is the exception

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   net.pipe://localhost/MyService
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

Server stack trace:     at

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress
>   address, Uri via)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.TakeConnection(EndpointAddress
>   address, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout,
>   TKey& key)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at

Inner Exception

> PipeException: "The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/MyService' could not be found on your local machine. "

Comment: Just to be clear - your client and your service are on the same machine? If not named pipes won't work...

Comment: @Murph, yes they are on the same machine.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Tsury please note that named pipes created by an elevated session aren't visible to normal users and vice-versa. That was the issue for me most of the time. I was running one app as a normal user and another "as administrator"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the client-side WCF channel stack failed when trying to derive from the service URL the actual name of the named pipe being used by the service. The service publishes the pipe name (which is a GUID which changes each time the service restarts) by placing a small structure in [a named shared memory section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which contains the GUID as one of its fields. The name used for the shared memory section is derived from the service URL by applying an algorithm which is compiled into both the server-side and client-side WCF code for the NetNamedPipeBinding.

The exception reported in the question really means that having applied the algorithm to the service URL to come up with a name, the client side code could not open a handle to a shared memory section of that name. This may mean, as the exception message states, that there is no service listening on the service URL used to derive the name. But it can instead mean that the memory section is there, and so is the service, but the client-side code is not running in a security context which allows it to access the shared memory.

On Windows platforms prior to Vista it is fairly unlikely that a WCF client would ever lack the security permissions to open the shared memory, read the pipe name GUID from it, and then successfully connect to the service's pipe. But on Vista and later platforms there are new security mechanisms which make this a much more common failure scenario.

Vista introduced a concept of different namespaces for named kernel objects: there is a Global (machine-wide) namespace, and a Private namespace for each logon session. The NetNamedPipeBinding client code will try both namespaces when looking for the shared memory section which advertises the pipe name. If the server has created the shared memory using a Global name, or if the service and the client are running in the same logon session, then the client will find what it is looking for. If, though, the service cannot create an object in the Global namespace (it always tries to do this first) then it will fall back to creating it the private session namespace, and then only clients running in the same session will be able to see it. Creating Global namespace kernel objects requires a special privilege in Vista and later platforms, which typically only Windows Service processes and applications running "As Administrator" will have. A common pitfall is to try to create a client in a Windows Service attempting to connect to a WCF NetNamedPipe service hosted in an application running in the interactive user session.

The Vista Mandatory Integrity Mechanism can also prevent a putative client connecting to a WCF NetNamedPipeBinding service, if the client code is running in a lower integrity context (e.g. a browser plug-in) than the code hosting the service.

I would imagine that the symptoms reported in the question, with test clients working but real clients not working, are almost certainly caused by the security context of the real clients being inconsistent with that of the service host, for one or other of these reasons.

Comment: This was the exact answer for my actual problem. For the record, I just had to start Visual Studio with Administrative permission to make it work. Also, starting both the client and the server from a command prompt was a solution. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't want to run it as admin? My processes are on the same session.

Comment: @chris-dickson Thanks for descriptive answer. I can confirm that NetNamedPipeBinding doesn't work when server is running inside local namespace and client is trying to connect from System user via global namespace. But I don't understand one thing. When I try to use NamedPipeClientStream and NamedPipeServerStream and try to replicate the scenario in which server is run from non-admin user and client is run from System user, then they connect correctly. How is this possible? What is the difference between NetNamedPipeBinding and NamedPipeStreams? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility to fix this root issue if searching for this error and coming across this post - if you are getting an error that no `net.pipe` address can be found at your url (i.e. `http://localhost:1234/MyService/etc/`) *make sure* that the **Net.Pipe Listener Adapter** Windows Service is *started*. (I also started Net.Tcp Listener Adapter)

The service does not seem to be enabled or started in some scenarios especially when deploying out to a remote server that might not of had a lot of the development tools installed that actively use these services. Starting the service fixed the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was... my site had been working properly, then suddenly stopped. Started up the service and everything ran fine afterwards.

Comment: Hallelujah! For future readers ::: To install this windows-service, I believe the path is ::: "Turn Windows Features on or off" /// ".NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services" /// "WCF Services" /// "Named Pipe Activation"     (If this service does not appear in your list of windows-services, you have to install it).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint used by your client has to match an endpoint exposed by your WCF service.  This means that the address/binding/contract tuple of the specified client endpoint must *exactly* match the address/binding/contract tuple of an endpoint exposed by your WCF service.  If you're using the app.config approach, make sure everything is spelled correctly in both the WCF service and client config files.  If you are adding the endpoints programmatically, make sure you haven't misspelled anything in the code.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, but this was not my case.

Comment: Does the login matters in this case? If a process owned by a user can access named pipes created by another user?

Comment: I don't know for sure.  I use named pipes to communicate from my local login client to my system-account Windows service on the same machine without issue.

Comment: @Jader: No doubt your need for an answer on this is long gone, but for posterity's sake and in the hope it may help others, I have posted an answer which I think explains what you saw.