# What might cause EndpointNotFoundException on local WCF named pipes?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I've got a system set up to let a worker process do some job and am coordinating with named pipes between the GUI process and the worker process. I kick off the worker process here:

```
this.pipeGuidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
  "VidCoderWorker.exe",
  Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + this.pipeGuidString);
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
this.worker = Process.Start(startInfo);

// When the process writes out a line, its pipe server is ready and can be contacted for
// work. Reading line blocks until this happens.
this.logger.Log("Worker ready: " + this.worker.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
  bool connectionSucceeded = false;

this.logger.Log("Connecting to process " + this.worker.Id + " on pipe " + this.pipeGuidString);

var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding
  {
    OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
  };

this.pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IHandBrakeEncoder>(
  this,
  binding,
  new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/" + pipeGuid + "/VidCoder"));

this.channel = this.pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
this.channel.Ping();
```

Then inside the worker process:

```
host = new ServiceHost(
  typeof (HandBrakeEncoder),
  new Uri[]
    {
      new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + PipeGuidString)
    });

host.AddServiceEndpoint(
  typeof (IHandBrakeEncoder),
  new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
  "VidCoder");

host.Open();

encodeComplete = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
Console.WriteLine("Service state is " + host.State + " on pipe " + PipeGuidString);
encodeComplete.Wait();

host.Close();
```

It works fine for most people (including me) 100% of the time. But one user reports that the host process *always* gets an EndpointNotFoundException when trying to connect to the worker process, even with a log that indicates that the GUID was the same on both sides and the state was Opened on the worker process.

I figure that he must have something different with his system that's causing the failure and am wondering what that could be.

- I've tried connecting via Remote Desktop and that still works for me.
- I have not changed the Mandatory Integrity level on either process
- I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477813/getting-endpointnotfoundexception-with-netnamedpipebinding-in-c-need-to-create) so I asked the user to run `net localgroup "NETWORK USERS"` but the group does not exist for him
- (edit) Net.Pipe Listener Adapter service was disabled for the user but it still did not work after the user enabled and started it.

Any other ideas about why this would be happening? I read some stuff about local vs global named pipes but since I'm communicating locally and spawning the process locally it didn't seem like it should be an issue.

(edit2) User was surprisingly able to get a WCF trace: http://engy.us/misc/TracesWithNetPipeStarted.svclog

(edit3) It apparently works when running the host process as Administrator. Could it be that in this case some part of the pipe communication was requiring those privileges? How can I set up the pipe channel so that it never needs admin?

Comment: Possibly an undetected exception in the worker. Do you have it all wrapped in try/catch with exception logging? Or is the worker running from a Task where you don't wait for the Task to finish at some point (which would lose exceptions from the task thread)?

Comment: As stated [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15691448/266143), is the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter service running? Also, does the exception have an InnerException?

Comment: It's all wrapped in a try/catch with logging. The connection is ready and working as far as the worker is concerned. About the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter service, I don't see it running when things are working correctly on my box. About the InnerException, I'm not logging that right now as it's part of a retry loop... does it normally have helpful information?

Comment: The Net.Pipe Listener Adapter was disabled for the user but it still did not work after they enabled and started it.

Comment: Did you try to enable wcf trace?

Comment: Added WCF trace submitted by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this SOA question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15987095/502194), which explains in detail how a WCF NetNamedPipeBinding service which is local to a particular session might be blocked by an unrelated application which is published globally, if the latter's service URL is chosen carelessly.

This seems quite a plausible explanation for the situation you describe.

Comment: The advice to use absolute URLs for endpoints looks promising and would apply in my situation. I haven't confirmed that it fixes it yet (since I don't have a problem repro myself) but it looks promising. I'll come back and accept the answer if it works out (but you can have the bounty for trying). :)

Comment: It turns out using absolute URLs for the endpoint did not fix it.

Comment: Did you investigate whether there was another service process running which was using the net.pipe binding? If there is, and *it* is using a relative URL with base address of just localhost, you won't be able to fix the problem just by changing your application's configuration (as explained in the linked answer).

Comment: BTW the WCF log trace shows that your client has connected to a pipe, but is getting a framing protocol fault during the preamble handshake (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/framing/faults/EndpointNotFound`, I think). I believe this is consistent with my theory that the client *is* rendezvousing with and connecting to a net.pipe service, but the wrong one.

Comment: Hah what do you know. He was running Garmin software as well. Too bad that the workaround doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that having installed Garmin Express interferes with Named Pipes. For instance, trying to run unit tests in VS in non-admin mode causes the test runner to hang. Uninstalling Garmin Express resolves the issue.

Comment: No, it doesn't interfere with Named Pipes per se... it interferes with the WCF endpoint publishing mechanism used by the WCF netNamedPipe binding. The test runner must be using this WCF binding.